# Kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_dispatch.c

Tags: kernel, bugs, gpu

OnePlus 7T smartphone randomly freezes and rebooting.

Bootloader unlocked and rooted. Smartphone runs on Android 11, but the same behavior occurred on a purely installed Android 12. Often the error appears in moments related to graphics, such as rotating the screen, changing the screen in games (the appearance of a video screensaver, for example). This can happen from once a day to several times.

From the logs it is clear that this is somehow related to video drivers:

```
[20240305_12:19:40.512637]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.622730]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: ----------------------[ GMU error ]----------------------
[20240305_12:19:40.622782]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Timeout waiting for lowest idle level 3
[20240305_12:19:40.622804]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Timestamps: 272b38cc6 272d3aee0 272d3af12
[20240305_12:19:40.622825]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: RPMH_POWER_STATE=0 SPTPRAC_PWR_CLK_STATUS=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622846]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: CX_BUSY_STATUS=71000000 CP_STATUS_1=1000000
[20240305_12:19:40.622868]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: RBBM_INT_UNMASKED_STATUS=1 PWR_COL_KEEPALIVE=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622889]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: CP2GMU_STATUS=0 CONTEXT_SWITCH_CNTL=0 AO_SPARE_CNTL=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622961]@0 ------------[ cut here ]------------
[20240305_12:19:40.623004]@0 WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 272 at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_a6xx_gmu.c:973 a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623024]@0 Modules linked in: wlan(O) rmnet_perf(O) machine_dlkm(O) wcd934x_dlkm(O) mbhc_dlkm(O) wcd9360_dlkm(O) swr_ctrl_dlkm(O) wcd9xxx_dlkm(O) tfa9894_dlkm(O) wsa881x_dlkm(O) wcd_core_dlkm(O) stub_dlkm(O) wcd_spi_dlkm(O) hdmi_dlkm(O) swr_dlkm(O) pinctrl_wcd_dlkm(O) usf_dlkm(O) native_dlkm(O) platform_dlkm(O) q6_dlkm(O) adsp_loader_dlkm(O) apr_dlkm(O) q6_notifier_dlkm(O) q6_pdr_dlkm(O) wglink_dlkm(O) msm_11ad_proxy [last unloaded: rmnet_perf]
[20240305_12:19:40.623200]@0 CPU: 0 PID: 272 Comm: kgsl_worker_thr Tainted: G S      W  O    4.14.190-perf+ #1
[20240305_12:19:40.623220]@0 Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SM8150 V2 PM8150 MTP 18865 19863 14 15 (DT)
[20240305_12:19:40.623243]@0 task: 00000000ead67ef5 task.stack: 000000007e72c1e2
[20240305_12:19:40.623263]@0 pc : a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623282]@0 lr : a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x44c/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623300]@0 sp : ffffff8014783980 pstate : 60c00145
[20240305_12:19:40.623316]@0 x29: ffffff80147839b0 x28: 0000000000000004 
[20240305_12:19:40.623348]@0 x27: 0000000000000002 x26: 0000000000000002 
[20240305_12:19:40.623379]@0 x25: ffffffe2b336e000 x24: 0000000000023b0c 
[20240305_12:19:40.623409]@0 x23: 0000000272d3af12 x22: 0000000272d3aee0 
[20240305_12:19:40.623440]@0 x21: 000000000001f888 x20: 0000000272b38cc6 
[20240305_12:19:40.623471]@0 x19: ffffff8b4a2fac00 x18: ffffff8b4a238000 
[20240305_12:19:40.623502]@0 x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffff8b4a45d000 
[20240305_12:19:40.623533]@0 x15: 4c544e435f455241 x14: 0000000000000060 
[20240305_12:19:40.623563]@0 x13: 0000000000000444 x12: 0000000810947aa9 
[20240305_12:19:40.623593]@0 x11: 0000000000000015 x10: 00000000000f4240 
[20240305_12:19:40.623624]@0 x9 : 610bdee29b856c00 x8 : 610bdee29b856c00 
[20240305_12:19:40.623655]@0 x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffffff8b4a45cdaa 
[20240305_12:19:40.623686]@0 x5 : 0000000000000034 x4 : 0000000000000008 
[20240305_12:19:40.623715]@0 x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : 000000000000006e 
[20240305_12:19:40.623746]@0 x1 : ffffff8b47f48d3c x0 : 00000000ffffff92 
[20240305_12:19:40.623780]@0 
PC: 0xffffff8b48696360:
[20240305_12:19:40.623797]@0 6360  9400632e f9400728 b0009a81 b85ec3a2 91238821 b94013e3 91004100 94006327
[20240305_12:19:40.623885]@0 6380  f9400728 b0009a81 29410be3 91245021 b94007e4 91004100 94006320 12800da0
[20240305_12:19:40.623965]@0 63a0  d4210000 9000dbc9 f85f83a8 f9404529 eb08013f 54000121 a9484ff4 f94023fb
[20240305_12:19:40.624046]@0 63c0  a94757f6 a9465ff8 a94567fa a9437bfd 910243ff d65f03c0 97e0a1aa d503201f
[20240305_12:19:40.624127]@0 
LR: 0xffffff8b4869635c:
[20240305_12:19:40.624142]@0 635c  91004100 9400632e f9400728 b0009a81 b85ec3a2 91238821 b94013e3 91004100
[20240305_12:19:40.624223]@0 637c  94006327 f9400728 b0009a81 29410be3 91245021 b94007e4 91004100 94006320
[20240305_12:19:40.624303]@0 639c  12800da0 d4210000 9000dbc9 f85f83a8 f9404529 eb08013f 54000121 a9484ff4
[20240305_12:19:40.624383]@0 63bc  f94023fb a94757f6 a9465ff8 a94567fa a9437bfd 910243ff d65f03c0 97e0a1aa
[20240305_12:19:40.624464]@0 
SP: 0xffffff8014783940:
[20240305_12:19:40.624480]@0 3940  486963a0 ffffff8b 60c00145 00000000 ffffffd0 ffffff80 499e7914 ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624560]@0 3960  ffffffff ffffffff 9b856c00 610bdee2 147839b0 ffffff80 486963a0 ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624638]@0 3980  147839b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
[20240305_12:19:40.624718]@0 39a0  01000000 71000000 9b856c00 610bdee2 14783a10 ffffff80 4865924c ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624797]@0 
[20240305_12:19:40.624815]@0 Call trace:
[20240305_12:19:40.624834]@0  a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.624857]@0  gmu_stop+0x34/0xf0
[20240305_12:19:40.624877]@0  gmu_core_stop+0x1c/0x28
[20240305_12:19:40.624901]@0  kgsl_pwrctrl_disable+0x70/0xb8
[20240305_12:19:40.624921]@0  _slumber+0x208/0x2e0
[20240305_12:19:40.624939]@0  kgsl_pwrctrl_change_state+0x234/0x510
[20240305_12:19:40.624962]@0  _adreno_start+0x2b8/0x958
[20240305_12:19:40.624981]@0  adreno_start+0x44/0x78
[20240305_12:19:40.624998]@0  _wake+0xc4/0x3f8
[20240305_12:19:40.625017]@0  kgsl_active_count_get+0x148/0x1e0
[20240305_12:19:40.625039]@0  sendcmd+0xe4/0x508
[20240305_12:19:40.625058]@0  _adreno_dispatcher_issuecmds+0x2a8/0x5b8
[20240305_12:19:40.625076]@0  adreno_dispatcher_work+0x450/0x9d0
[20240305_12:19:40.625101]@0  kthread_worker_fn+0x80/0x168
[20240305_12:19:40.625119]@0  kthread+0x11c/0x130
[20240305_12:19:40.625141]@0  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x1c
[20240305_12:19:40.625158]@0 ---[ end trace 137859bf8ec69b6e ]---
[20240305_12:19:40.625228]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Failed to stop GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.625690]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |_wake| start failed -110
[20240305_12:19:40.625985]@1 kgsl kgsl-3d0: RB[-1]: gmu fault status 00000001 rb 0000/0000 ib1 0000000000000000/0000 ib2 0000000000000000/0000
[20240305_12:19:40.626077]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| GPU PAGE FAULT: addr = 0 pid= 0 name=unknown
[20240305_12:19:40.626104]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| context=gfx3d_user TTBR0=0x3000273352000 CIDR=0x0 (read translation fault)
[20240305_12:19:40.626129]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| FAULTING BLOCK: CP
[20240305_12:19:40.626178]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: ---- nearby memory ----
[20240305_12:19:40.626200]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: *EMPTY*
[20240305_12:19:40.626219]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0:  <- fault @ 00000000
[20240305_12:19:40.626236]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: *EMPTY*
[20240305_12:19:40.627643]@1 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.633654]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:40.742778]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.774568]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.780103]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:40.882739]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.914491]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.920147]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:41.022673]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:41.054826]@1 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:41.060742]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:41.162731]@3 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:41.192733]@3 ------------[ cut here ]------------
[20240305_12:19:41.192774]@3 kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_dispatch.c:2270!
[20240305_12:19:41.192799]@3 Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[20240305_12:19:41.192816]@3 Modules linked in: wlan(O) rmnet_perf(O) machine_dlkm(O) wcd934x_dlkm(O) mbhc_dlkm(O) wcd9360_dlkm(O) swr_ctrl_dlkm(O) wcd9xxx_dlkm(O) tfa9894_dlkm(O) wsa881x_dlkm(O) wcd_core_dlkm(O) stub_dlkm(O) wcd_spi_dlkm(O) hdmi_dlkm(O) swr_dlkm(O) pinctrl_wcd_dlkm(O) usf_dlkm(O) native_dlkm(O) platform_dlkm(O) q6_dlkm(O) adsp_loader_dlkm(O) apr_dlkm(O) q6_notifier_dlkm(O) q6_pdr_dlkm(O) wglink_dlkm(O) msm_11ad_proxy [last unloaded: rmnet_perf]
[20240305_12:19:41.192984]@3 Process kgsl_worker_thr (pid: 272, stack limit = 0x000000007e72c1e2)
[20240305_12:19:41.193004]@3 CPU: 3 PID: 272 Comm: kgsl_worker_thr Tainted: G S      W  O    4.14.190-perf+ #1
[20240305_12:19:41.193018]@3 Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SM8150 V2 PM8150 MTP 18865 19863 14 15 (DT)
[20240305_12:19:41.193033]@3 task: 00000000ead67ef5 task.stack: 000000007e72c1e2
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error? Or why might this be happening?

Comment: Such problems usually can not be fixed by end users. Often drivers like graphic drivers are only available as pre-compiled elements that can be integrated into a certain kernel version. If the mentioned source code is public or only available to paying manufacturer is unknown to me. Without source code understanding what a kernel driver is doing is already complicated. Fixing it requires advanced skills in reverse engineering and kernel debugging - you won't find much people that can do so. I don't know anybody.

Comment: The strangest thing for me is that I have had this smartphone for several years and for several of these years I have been using the same version of Android, the same applications. There was no such problem before. I assume this bug appeared with the update of some Google system applications? –

Comment: In that case there is another possibility: a hardware problem. The silicon chips degrades continuously when used, on atomic level "holes" can appear and grow. This decreased the maximum speed the transistor can switch power. If you now try to use the full power of the chip it struggles and the driver will crash.